# Can't unlock tablet

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, recovery-mode, google-account

I've got this Estar Beauty HD Quad-Core tablet running android kitkat (4.4) and I've recentlyforgotten my unlock pattern. I've forgotten my google account so I can't unlock it with google. It also can't boot into  recovery mode.
 pls help!
I really need that tablet!
Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean it cannot boot into recovery mode?

Comment: I turn it off then press vol -  and power button at the same time, nothing I press vol + and power button and still nothing.

Comment: I’m not familiär with Rockchip; depending on the chip manufacturer different things need to be done to get into recovery mode, eg. vol+ and vol- at the same time while pressing the power button? Power not connected? Tried multiple times? PS: Downvoting new members is not cool, especially without explanation. What did joni in particular do wrong to deserve this?

Comment: I need recovery mode because then I can factory reset the tablet.

Comment: Check the documentation of the chip manufacturer (or try what was written above).

Comment: I tried what you said but nothing. Maybe this model is so rare that you can't find an article about it on the web.